# rails create model with sub attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am new to rails and building an app to fetch json data from an external website and save it in the database. The json has the following fields under User:

{
    "id": ,
    "name": " ",
    "username": " ",
    "email": " ",
    "address": {
      "street": " ",
      "suite": " ",
      "city": " ",
      "zipcode": " ",
      }
    "phone": " ",
    "website": " "
    },

I know how to create a User model with name, username, and email. But how do I add address that has multiple sub-attributes. I did not see "array" as an option to choose from for creating model.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by associating addresses to a user.

First you should create a new model called user_address for example, with the attributes you desire:

```
rails g model user_address address:string number:integer user_id:integer
```

On your user_address.rb file:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Then, in your user.rb file you should add

```
has_many :user_addresses
```

Once you do this you'll be able to access all the user's addresses by doing the following query:

```
user.user_addresses
```

this will give you an 'ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy' object, where you will be able to iterate:

```
user.user_addresses.each do |address_instance|
  puts address_instance.address+"#{ address_instance.number}"
end
```

To manage this in a form, you could follow this guide: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms

Comment: I was not sure if I needed to create two different models( User and User_address) since each user have unique id, name, username, email, address, phone and website. I thought I could add address as an attribute and use street, suite, city zipcode as an array for address attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
class NameOfYourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    add_column :your_models, :address, :text
  end

end

class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base 
 serialize :address, Hash  # if your variable is a Hash
 serialize :address, Array # or for an Array
end
```